# is it impact the search operations if we manually generate document ids for firebase database?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, angularfire5

I am trying to write an optimized search functionality using firestore database and angularfire with angular6 so, what would be good to have manually generated or auto-generated Document IDs?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Following the best practices will help your questions get answered! You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Auto-generated document-ID's are cost less code and are easier to maintain. Less code means less risk on bugs